# Magento backup taking too long

Tags: database, backup

So, I decided to make a database backup from the magento admin panel. But it´s taking too long and there´s no way to know if the backup is actually working or if it got stucked.
Is there a way to stop the process without losing data? I can´t access to any other admin panel utility or make any purchase on my store.

Comment: Do you want only backup of database? You can try sqlyog for database backup

Comment: Did you use this feature https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/system/backups.html ?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a backup by commands.

```
mysqldump -u username -p dbname > db_dump.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Backup time depends on how many products & customers you have.

You can truncate all log data in your database.

1. Instead of Manual backup , you can take backup at night time by setting scheduled backup

   > System > Configuration > Advanced > system> Scheduled backup setttings
2. Also, you can take backup in **phpmyadmin** by importing the Database.
3. If you have ssh access, you can take backup by commands.

   > mysql -uUSER -p -hHOST DB_NAME < db_dump.sql

Answer (score 0):

Yes Admin backup will take too long. Please check whether you selected maintenance mode while taking backup. If so go-to your root folder, and delete maintenance.flag file.

Sometimes the backup process will be running in the background, to kill that restart your webserver or if you know the pid of the backup process, you can kill that through ssh

In order to take backup from ssh use below command

```
mysqldump -u dbusername -p dbname > backupname.sql.
```

It will ask for password after entering this. Please note password is not visible while typing. Otherwise you can use this other version but not recommended.

```
mysqldump -u dbusername -pPassword dbname > backupname.sql.
```

You can immediately type password after -p option without any space as it is. I used capital P just for a notation.